# Run the controller's Action Automatically which is hosted on net

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller which I want to run automatically regardless whether or not the instance of that *website* is created or not. For example, I have a controller called payment. If the payment is pending then automatically mail should go to the client.

Suppose my controller is

```
public class PaymentEmailController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   //some code for sending mail
   return View("Login","Home");
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a workflow (e.g. K2, WF) instead?

Comment: NO.without any Workflow.

Comment: Or you can create Windows Service.

Comment: Its a website.how can i create the Windows Service.if i create it,it will work?

Comment: You can create windows service project which will process all pending payments from database.

Comment: Thanks for replying.i am creating the Website.can i marge the windows service with web application?

Comment: I think you should create separate project for windows service and reuse code from web application project.

Comment: Like WCF services , that we build separately and use it our application?

Comment: I guess what people have been suggesting here is that it is not the frontend's job to do business logic tasks like what you are trying to achieve with your controller. You will need to outsource such task somewhere, like in a different project, be it a new service or workflow (my original suggestion).

Comment: @Alex R,Can you please provide the link or reference code so that i am start using it or get initial knowledge of its working.